# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UserController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, controller

Hello I am developing an application about registration of users, but when the user X wants to edit his information the app is taking "edit" instead of user id and shows me the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UserController#show

Couldn't find User with id=edit
```

(I am using devise for the users), this is my home.html.rb

```
<body>
<div class="container">

  <% if signed_in? %>
    <table class="front" summary="For signed-in users">
      <tr>
        <td class="main">
          <h1 class="micropost">What's up?</h1>
          <%= link_to "edit your profile", edit_user_registration_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <% else %>

    <h1>Sample App</h1>
    <p>
    This is the home page for the <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> sample application.
    </p>
    <%= link_to "Sign up now!", new_user_registration_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
```

Here is my routes.rb (I know it should be users but if i put that as plural don`t work)

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "static_pages#home"
match '/contact', :to=>'static_pages#contact'
match '/about', :to=>'static_pages#about'
get "user/:id" => "User#show"
devise_for :user
resources :user do
end
```

At last here is my UserController

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

def new
     @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to user_session_path
    else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
end

end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    #redirect_to @user
end
end
```

Comment: also i put the trace

    app/controllers/user_controller.rb:18:in `show'

Comment: Because you have singular resources, that won't work for multiple users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a user id in order for Rails to generate the correct routes.

```
edit_user_registration_path ( USER_ID )
```

You didn't pass any user_id to the method in your home.html.erb.